# ILMerging Windows Forms application with couple localizations problem

Tags: winforms, localization, ilmerge

I've created a Windows Forms (C#) application called "Image Processing". It uses many external dlls so I decided to use ILMerge to merge all of them into one exe file and it worked. But today I've localized my application. After building I had 3 new folders in Debug folder: "en-US", "ru-RU", "uk-UA" with one dll with the same name "ImageProcessing.resources.dll". So I included all of them in a ILMerge command:

```
ILMerge.exe /t:winexe /out:ImageProcessingRelease.exe ImageProcessing.exe AForge.dll AForge.Imaging.dll AForge.Math.dll DevExpress.Data.v10.2.dll DevExpress.Utils.v10.2.dll DevExpress.XtraBars.v10.2.dll DevExpress.XtraEditors.v10.2.dll FreeImageNET.dll uk-UA\ImageProcessing.resources.dll ru-RU\ImageProcessing.resources.dll en-US\ImageProcessing.resources.dll
```

My program stores language locale in settings. After merging I can't change language, but settings are changing.

I don't know what else I can include here for more details so tell me please what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. ILMerge is not suitable in this case, as .NET Framework relies on the folder structure to determine which resource file to use.

It is meaningless to combine assemblies in that way, and some third party assembly vendor's end user license does not permit you to merge their product with your own assemblies.